# How to get a white image using numpy?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I tried to make a 64px picture of white image with a black bar on top. The black bar just came out fine. The white part was messed up.

```
from IPython.display import Image as im
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(shape=(64,4))
b = 255*np.ones(64)
c = 255*np.ones(shape=(64,3))
d = np.column_stack((c,b))
for i in range (63):
  a = np.block([[[a]],[[d]]])
print(a.shape)

image = Image.fromarray(a, "RGB")
image.save("white.png", "PNG")
display(im('white.png'))
```

The output came like this

[image: The output came like this]

The expected image was the exact opposite of this. Just the white and black portions switch places. Black at top and white at bottom.

[image: The expected image was the exact opposite of this. Just the white and black portions switch places. Black at top and white at bottom.]

Comment: Can you show an 'expected output'?

Comment: @amzon-ex, A second link is added into the question which is the exact opposite of the expected output.  The exact required output looks something like this [image](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/16180786?hl=en). I meant only the photo. Please ignore the question in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to answer you if you provided decent expected and actual input/output images and code. If you want folk to help you, it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them

In answer, I suspect the `dtype` of your images is incorrect. Try checking with:

```
print(a.dtype)
```

Try correcting by specifying the `dtype` on instantiation with:

```
a = np.zeros((64,64), dtype=np.uint8)
```